# Send AJAX request with jQuery on Click

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, onclick

I am trying to send an Ajax request after a link is clicked on my page. My setup is like this: Someone clicks on a link that displays a modal popup. It then asks them to "Confirm" their action by clicking "Yes". If they click "Yes", I send the Ajax request to do the action selected. However, for some reason, my code is not triggering the Ajax code. My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ajax-remove-completion-date').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'post-update.php',
                cache:false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#success-remove-completion-date').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#myModal1" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove Completion Date</a>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Remove Completion Date</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to remove the students Completion Date?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn blue" data-dismiss="modal" id="ajax-remove-completion-date">Yes</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="remove-completion-date" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the code where you handle the modal popup "yes" trigger?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/nGzRq/ - The ajax request is working on JSfiddle, although it's a 404

Comment: @NabilKadimi I do not see it working?

Comment: @three3 I can see it in my browsor console... Anyways, use a  `window.alert('bla')` inside your success callback and see if it's firing.

Comment: @NabilKadimi I just added the window.alert tot he code but it did not fire. Any other suggestions? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had the jQuery code loaded before I had my jQuery loaded. I hate when I do this1

Comment: Aha, you should always wrap your jQuery code in `.ready()`  - http://api.jquery.com/ready/